# Android - slow memory allocation for big count of objects

Tags: java, android, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have app for android, where I need to load some file and process every string in that file and works further with this processed strings.
So I created class `Entry` for processed line and holder for this Entries - class `EntryManager`, which looks like this:

```
public class EntryManager {

    private static EntryManager instance;

    private List<Entry> rules  = new ArrayList<>();

    public static synchronized EntryManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new EntryManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void addRule(String rule) {
        rules.add(RulesParser.parseRule(rule));
    }

    public void clear() {
        rules.clear();
    }
}
```

Entry class is quite simple - it contains original `String` line and few boolean flags. General count of entries is ~70'000, so will be created 70'000 objects.

The problem is:
the first time it takes 0.3 seconds to finish, but all other times it takes ~7 seconds. Is is possible to avoid without using NDK?

**UPD. Looks like it was my fail - during testing my phone was connected to PC via cable, when I took it out everything became ok**

Comment: How do you load it? And define `it works for n seconds`

Comment: @Zoe System.currentTimeMillis() before and after file processing